# cannot import name 'pad_sequences' from 'keras.preprocessing.sequence'

Tags: python, keras, python-import

i'm trying to import these :

```
from numpy import array
from keras.preprocessing.text import one_hot

from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences


from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Activation, Dropout, Dense
from keras.layers import Flatten, LSTM
from keras.layers import GlobalMaxPooling1D
from keras.models import Model
```

But i'm getting error as cannot import name 'pad_sequences' from 'keras.preprocessing.sequence'

Can anyone help me here please?

Answer (score 79):

Replace:

```
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
```

With:

```
from keras_preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
```

Comment: I'm curious why this worked. Could you provide more info about it?

Comment: they restructured the module

Answer (score 52):

According to the TensorFlow v2.10.0 doc, the correct path to pad_sequences is tf.keras.utils.pad_sequences. So in your script one should write:

```
from keras.utils import pad_sequences
```

It has resolved the problem for me.

Comment: Thanks! This helped me as well. Any reason why this worked but not other patterns? Again module restructuring?

Answer (score 21):

you can use this. It is worked for me.

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

most likely you are using tf version 2.9 - go back to 2.8 and the same path works

alternatively import it as:

```
from keras.utils.data_utils import pad_sequences
```

TF is not so stable with paths - the best way is check their git source corresponding to the version you succeeded to install !! in the case of TF2.9 you can see how it is imported [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/5541781cf29e6315c57df63172fee6fcdc1cc984/keras/utils/__init__.py)

Answer (score 2):

I came across the same problem just now but still don't know what is going on(still waiting for an answer).
I gave up importing pad_sequences and write it in full and it works

```
keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences()
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct path to import is keras.io.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences. Your path lacks the io.

```
from keras.io.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import sequence
```

worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
from keras.utils import pad_sequences
```